# how to get data in latitude and longitude in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to get data in variable php.i want latitude and longitude after dragging marker into view class.iam getting latitude and longitude proper on alert().

$latitude=?
$longitude=?

```
    //map
    $this->load->library('googlemaps');

    $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1419';
    $marker['draggable'] = true;

    //working alert on view and popup latitude and lontitude
    $marker['ondragend'] = 'alert(\'You just dropped me at: \' + event.latLng.lat() + \', \' + event.latLng.lng());';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    $arr['latitude']=?

    //location need which is popup in alert() as event.latLng.lng()
    $arr['longitude']=?
```

Answer (score 0):

//try it in javascript

```
    function loadMap() 
    {
       var a=(document.getElementById("la").value);
       var b=(document.getElementById("lo").value); ;

       var mapOptions = {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(a,b ),
          zoom:17
       }

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("your div id"),mapOptions);

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(a, b),
          map: map
       });
    }
```